# Execute a function based on window inner width

Tags: jquery

I need to start a function (scrollTop) when the window width is equal or less than about 500px, then execute function scrollTop under an if statement for add a class on a label tag, but in this way nothing works :(

Here the code:

```
function screenClass() {
    if($(window).innerWidth() < 484) {
        //alert("500");
        function AddClass() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $(".show-menu").addClass("sticky");
            } else {
                $(".show-menu").removeClass("sticky");
            }
        }

    }
}
$(window).bind("resize",function(){
    screenClass();
});

<label id="navbar" for="show-menu" class="show-menu">
<img class="icon l" src="/website/img/menu.png" /><img class="icon r" src="/website/img/menu.png" />
MENU
</label>
```

Need this to make the menu bar sticky when i scroll the page.
Hope in your help.
Thanks!

Comment: Where do you call `AddClass()`?

Comment: if the IF condition is true, but not work...

Comment: You're just defining the function, you never call it.

Comment: You don't need `function AddClass()`, just put the code that you want to run directly in the `if`.

Answer (score 1):

You're defining a function `AddClass()`, but never calling it. There's no need to define a function at all, just do what the function does.

If you want to specify action that should occur when the window scrolls, it needs to be inside a `scroll` event handler.

```
function screenClass() {
  $(window).off("scroll");
  if ($(window).innerWidth() < 484) {
    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $(".show-menu").addClass("sticky");
      } else {
        $(".show-menu").removeClass("sticky");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: The code needs to be inside a `scroll` event handler.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but again, no class is added... :(

Comment: Can you add a [mcve] to your question? It's hard to understand what it's supposed to do without the HTML and CSS.

Comment: It would be better if you put it in the question using [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/715zv2k9/ - in this fiddle your code is working, now i don't understand why the class is not applied in my code...

EDIT: I have tested again on my code, now everything is working fine!!!
Thanks a lot! :)